# Rails caching remote link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of items and above it I have a few links that allow you to filter the list but after you click on these links once, WebBrick returns 304 Not Modified. The items in the list can be changed in the list and so these filter links are showing out of date information. My view looks like this:

app/views/items/index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'All', {action:'filter', filter:'all'}, remote:true %>
<%= link_to 'To Buy', {action:'filter', filter:'to_buy'}, remote:true %>
<div id="items">
    <%= render 'items' %>
</div>
```

WebBrick is running in development mode so caching shouldn't be turned on. I could set the method to something other than GET but technically that wouldn't be correct. Is there any option to make sure link_to doesn't return cached content? I'm using Rails 3.2.13.

app/controllers/items_controller.rb:

```
def filter        
  case params[:filter]
    when 'to_buy' then
      @items=Item.where('to_buy=?', true)
    when 'all' then
      @items=Item.all
  end
end
```

app/views/items/filter.js.erb:

```
$('#items').html("<%=j render 'items' %>");
```

**UPDATE**

The only solution I could come up with was to turn the link_tos into normal HTML links and get JQuery to do the ajax request with cache set to false:

app/views/items/index.html.erb:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="filter_link" data-filter="all">All</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="filter_link" data-filter="to_buy">To Buy</a>
```

app/assets/javascripts/items.js.coffee:

```
$('.filter_link').click ->
  filter=$(this).data('filter')
  $.ajax "items/filter/#{filter}", cache:false
```

Comment: Is it really hitting the controller action? the links dont have controller name

Comment: It's hitting the controller each time (WebBrick is outputting the SQL that it's executing) but returning a 304 response to the browser. The controller attribute isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [kaminari gem](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari) for pagination, and they have an option for remote=true. What happens then is that it generates a link_to remote, and also append a random number to the url, so that WebBrick does not return cached page.
The url would look something like: `http://youdomain.com/your/path?_=1518477167725`
I'm assuming this number at the end is a time_stamp. Since the url will never match the url in cache, it will force it to reload.

You could do something like this in your link_to, so you can still user `remote=true` and won't need custom ajax.